# Finger Print Authentication not ready in ionic3

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have just downloaded a source code from git hub which has bio-metric authentication for login using ionic 3 and the link is [Bio-metric authentication](https://github.com/NihinlolaFaj/BiometricAuthenticationApp.git)

After downloading the zip package i have installed @node-modules by *npm install*

Then i have did *ionic serve* and *ionic build cordova android*.

The android version in the app is `6.3.0`

Then i just needed to test it in a android mobile . So i used `Redmi Note 4` for debugging in google developer tools.

Now on Login i got this error.

> Uncaught (in promise): Fingerprint authentication not ready.

What may be the issue? Is it the Android version? Or do i need to add any other plugins?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try surrounding your block of code that uses FingerprintAIO to check something in `this.platform.ready().then(() => {`. This error may happen due to the plugin not being ready to fire. 
Also are you always getting the issue and is it breaking the app?
And for the android version after Android 6.0 the plugin should work just fine.